# Loop over a character in R

Tags: r, loops, character

I want to loop over the values of certain variable, specified as `tname = ...` in the code below, to get different regression results. The command I use (`att_gt`) asks for only character variables ni `tname`. However, my loop is not able to transform the variable into a character correctly.

This is what I tried:

```
library(did)
for(i in 1999:2021){
att_gt(yname  = "y",
      gname  = "g",
      idname = "panelid",
      tname  = i,
      xformla = ~ 1,
      data = d)
}
```

However, I get an error that says that I did not introduced the correct variable.

I also tried:

```
for(i in as.character(1999:2021){...}
```

And this:

```
...
tname = as.character(i)
...
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When there is an error, it very much helps to paste the exact error above where it occurred to help us replicate & etc.

Comment: The `?att_gt` documentation describes the `tname` argument as *"The name of the column containing the time periods"*. Do you have a separate column for each year, one column named `"1999"`, one column named `"2000"`, etc.?

Comment: In the examples at the bottom of the `?att_gt` help page, the sample data has a single `year` column and they use `tname = "year"`. That might be a better way to structure your data. If that's not how your data is structured now which we can't see... could you add a few rows of sample data to your question so we can see what your input looks like?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have only one var to signal year.  The command runs without problem when I do not use loops and directly input the tname variable (year).
This is the structure of my data:
           y                year  g
       <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1       116           1990  1996
 2       120           1990  1997
 3       149           1990  1998
 4       112           1990  1999
 5        73           1990  2000
 6       139           1990  2001

Comment: It's hard to read your structure in comments, please edit it into your question with proper formatting. But it looks like you don't have a column named `"1991"`, so `tname = "1991"` as in your loop doesn't make sense because `tname` is supposed to be a column name. Perhaps you can also clarify your goal when you edit the data into your question.